# Symfony2 new project does not load resources

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I'm new to `Symfony2` and am trying to follow a tutorial to create a simple project. I downloaded Symfony and opened `web/config.php`. I can see the content of the page but none of the resources (css and images) loaded. I'm very new to symfony and searched for a long time but can't find the solution. Can anyone help me with it?

Here's a screen shot of my `config.php` and the `config.php` from the tutorial:
[image]

I also noticed that when I click the three links on the page the link doesn't take me to its proper target. For example, it takes me to `http://localhost/web/config.php/app_dev.php/_configurator/` when the proper link should have been `http://localhost/web/app_dev.php/_configurator/`. Notice that what it does is that it didn't remove the `config.php` from the url. Given the infamous fact that php doesn't handle relative directive intuitively my guess is that this is the root of the problem. However, I'm really new to symfony and don't know how to fix this.

Thanks

---

Edit:
I'm using apache2.4 on Windows

Comment: are you using nginx/apache/or php's server?

Comment: Please, add the configuration of your web server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just seems like you haven't correctly installed the static assets.

Try the following command on your shell:

`cd /path/to/project
php app/console assets:install web`

Alternatively, if you're using a filesystem that supports symbolic links (#nowindows)

`php app/console assets:install web --symlink`

then refresh the config page - that should do it.

Comment: Help! It's happening again! After solving it yesterday I just left it there and the same problem happened again today. I tried `assets:install web` and it doesn't work. The images and css are all in the directories but they are not loading.

Comment: I think if you recompile with `assets:install web` new and edited files will be affected. The only problem I ever walked into were old abundant assets laying in the `/web[/css|/js|/bundles]` directory. Similar to the [AcmeDemoBundle removement](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/remove.html#remove-bundle-assets) I deleted them manually.

For developing also have a closer look to the [`assetic:watch`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) function. It might be helpful.

Comment: why is this happening, I run the symfony installer on a fresh system and I get the OP's problem :/ solved it with your solution, but am wondering why did it happen in the first place? the `web/bundles` directory contained zero-byte files before running `php app/console assets:install web`